# Hiding Cancel button on ABPeoplePickerNavigationController in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I am attempting to hide the cancel button of the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. The following code works fine when run in the iOS 7.1 simulator, correctly hiding the button. However, it has no effect when run in the iOS 8.4 simulator. In both cases, the log message is written to the debugger, so I know that the code is executing.

Besides this code, I have also tried subclassing ABPeoplePickerNavigationController (even though the Apple docs say not to) and setting the button to nil in the viewDidLoad method, but that has no effect on iOS 8 either.

Googling this, there are many posts asking how to do this, most with answers. However, none of the answers appear to work in iOS 8. I have also tried the solution suggested in the following post (along with many others) with no success.

[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController - remove "Cancel" button without using private methods/properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611499/abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-remove-cancel-button-without-using-privat)

Has anyone found a way to hide the cancel button of the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController in iOS 8?

```
-(void)showPeoplePickerController
{
     ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
     picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
     picker.delegate = self;

     // Display only a person's phone, email, and birthdate
     NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty],
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonBirthdayProperty], nil];

     picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
     // Show the picker
     [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
     NSLog(@"Attempting to hide cancel button...");
     navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = nil;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO`?

Comment: Just tried it. With iOS 8 it has no effect. If you switch the simulator to iOS 7, the button is disabled. Even if it did work, it wouldn't quite accomplish what I'm trying to do since the button is still visible. It does further illustrate, however, that Apple is doing something different in iOS 8. I'm guessing they are trying to stop people from using that controller as anything other than a quick picker. 

I went ahead and wrote my own view that loads contacts in a UITableView. It's a bit more work since you have to group them into a dictionary in order to generate the index, but it works.